# inserting multiple records with same value in sql database using php

Tags: php

I'm working on a library management system & i want to insert no of records as equal to no of copies specified by user.this code does this but sometimes it adds 1 less entry.

```
  <?php
    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $authore=$_POST["aut"];
    $doa=$_POST["doa"];
    $cst=$_POST["cst"];
    $noc=$_POST["noc"];
    $tag= implode("," , $_POST["checkbox"]);
    $ses=$_SESSION['session'];
    session_start();
    require_once("../db.php");

    for($i=$noc;$i>0;$i--)
    {
    $bno=$_POST["bno"][$i];
    $qry="insert into addbook(bookno,title,authore,tags,session,status,dateofarrival,customtag,noofcopies)values('$bno','$title','$authore','
    $tag','$ses','0','$doa','$cst','$noc')";
    mysql_query($qry);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is `$noc`?. If always add 1 less record use `$i>=0` in `for` condition

Comment: It seems that your $_POST["bno"][0] is not inserting. Change loop to for($i=$noc;$i>=0;$i--)

Comment: sorry i accidentally approved edit , i should not have approved that edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost

Answer (score 0):

It's adding one less because you specified `$i>0`,so it will always start from 1 instead do like this:

```
for($i=$noc;$i>=0;$i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start session before you specifying any session variable...

just check it..

```
<?php
$title=$_POST["title"];
    $authore=$_POST["aut"];
    $doa=$_POST["doa"];
    $cst=$_POST["cst"];
    $noc=$_POST["noc"];
    $tag= implode("," , $_POST["checkbox"]);
    $ses=$_SESSION['session'];
    session_start();
    require_once("../db.php");
```

Change

```
<?php
session_start();
$title=$_POST["title"];
    $authore=$_POST["aut"];
    $doa=$_POST["doa"];
    $cst=$_POST["cst"];
    $noc=$_POST["noc"];
    $tag= implode("," , $_POST["checkbox"]);
    $ses=$_SESSION['session'];

    require_once("../db.php");
```

may this help otherwise in php you can try debugging, for example, use `mysqli_error()` etc.